# Multiple mac adrress on one cisco switch interface

Tags: cisco, switch, mac-address, interface, netconf

How can i config Multiple mac address on one cisco switch interface?
(I have 3 laptops and i connect only one laptop every time(I switch between them), and i want to config only one interface with the 3 mac address and block all the other interfaces(security motives). I think i prefer that on port security, and open and block every time i connect laptop on the switch.
Can someone help me and explain to me how to conf that?
Thank you all

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have multiple MAC address on Single Port. Port Security is somewhat different. It is allowed only specific MAC addresses through port. That particular port only allow to transfer data for permitted mac addresses.

If you want to allow only 3 computers, best way is shutdown other ports and enable port security in that particular port. Additionally you can use Dynamic VLAN also.

https://community.cisco.com/t5/networking-documents/how-to-configure-port-security-on-cisco-catalyst-switches-that/ta-p/3132907

Comment: Oh i think i get you ,dyanmic vlan sounds like a good option.. you meant create a vlan with 3 computers and con that on the port and shut down all the other ports right?

Comment: that also one option. but i don't see such a requirement because your requirement is not a vlan purpose. dynamic vlan is somewhat different. please search it on google.

Comment: Thank you so much!!i actually tried to find out about dynamic vlan and how to config that but i didnt understand really:/ can you maybe explain me that shortly..?

Comment: https://www.ciscopress.com/articles/article.asp?p=29803&seqNum=2

Comment: Emm still try to understand why you prefer a dynamic vlan over static... i have only one switch so dont need vtp

Comment: you want to allow only 3 mac address. You have two option. 1. port security. it is allowed mentioned mac address. it is best solution. dynamic vlan also doing same thing. when you connect computer it will assign particular vlan. it also solution. best solution is port security. i have clearly mention that.